# taking screenShots using a lot of memory in delphi

Tags: delphi, memory-management, screenshot

This question has been asked before but the problem was the size of the picture , my problem is the using of memory that keeps increasing until the the program crashes

The idea is to keep capturing the desktop.

Here is my code:

```
unit GetDesktop;
...
 function capture:tbitmap;
 var vDesktopDC: HDC;
 begin
  Result  := tbitmap.Create;
  vDesktopDC := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
   Result.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
   Result.Height := Screen.Height;
   Result.Width := Screen.Width;
   BitBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height, vDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
 finally
ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, vDesktopDC);
end;

end;
```

-

```
unit main;
 ...
 procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var look:boolean;
 begin
 look := true;
 repeat
 application.ProcessMessages;
 image1.Picture.Bitmap:=capture;
 capture.Free;
 until look = false;

 end;
```

Comment: The line with `capture.Free;` creates another instance of a bitmap which you immediately `Free`. You need to keep the reference to the instance from the first call of `capture`. I would start from scratch with a procedure into which you'll pass an existing bitmap instance (e.g. that `image1.Picture.Bitmap`) as parameter.

Comment: @TLama  you mean i should use that line the unit getdesktop ?

Comment: A simple search reveals lots of resources on this subject - http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips1999/qt/deskscreenshot.htm

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The problem is that you are overwriting the reference to the bitmap instance created previously (`image1.Picture.Bitmap:=capture`). You are trying to release it (`capture.Free`), but that actually creates another instance which you immediately release.

Comment: If your app is going to run 24*7, instead of individual snapshots, you'd do better to base your screen-handling on one of the remote-desktop libraries for Delphi.  The likes of VNC couldn't possibly work if they had to continually send entire snapshots of the screen to the remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image1.Picture.Bitmap:=capture;
capture.Free;
```

Here `capture` is a function. You call the function twice and so take two screenshots. You create two new bitmaps and only free one of them.

You might do well to change the name of `capture` to `GetScreenshot`. Then declare a local variable named `Bitmap`.

```
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
```

Then link it all up like this:

```
Bitmap := GetScreenshot;
try
  Image1.Picture.Assign(Bitmap);
finally
  Bitmap.Free;
end;
```

Of course, it may be cleaner still to pass the bitmap associated with the image control to the screenshot function and get it to blit directly there rather than have an intermediate bitmap.

Comment: thnx man . it seems that i posted my answer before i saw yours . it's working great

Answer (score 0):

soo . i tried this

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var look:boolean;
b:tbitmap;
begin
look := true;
repeat
application.ProcessMessages;
 try
b:=capture;
 image1.Picture.Bitmap:=b;
 finally
 FreeAndNil(b)
 end;
until look = false;
```

and the memory usage is stable at 7044 k (before it was getting alooooot more)
if someone have a better solution it would be great :)

Edit by HeartWare: The generally accepted way to format the above code (not my own style)

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Look : Boolean;
  b    : TBitmap;

begin
  look:=true;
  repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    b:=capture;
    try
      image1.Picture.Bitmap:=b;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(b)
    end;
  until not look;
end;
```

Comment: I've gave you the example and you are doing it wrong again - http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips1999/qt/deskscreenshot.htm

Comment: You put the `try` in the wrong place, and the indentation is terrible. You are bound to make mistakes if you don't indent code in a sane manner.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i'm still a noob . i would appriciate it if u take it easy on me , beside if i knew evrything , i wouldn't come to here in the first place

Comment: That's why I have offered the advice. I don't think going easy is helpful to you. Clearly you want to learn which is excellent, so how does it help for us to hold back? My comment just stated what I perceive to be facts.

Comment: yeah . guys . if you point directly the the part i done wrong , that would be great

Comment: I have supplied a (I think) generally acceptable formatting and indention of your code. One comment, however: You are creating an infinite loop - there's no way the variable "look" will ever become false, so the program will continue to execute your code for all eternity, and you won't be able to stop it (short of terminating it from the Task Manager or cancelling the debug session if you are debugging). Also, I would probably use Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(b); instead of the assignment, to illustrate, that it isn't a reference assignment, but a kind of "deep copy" that is performed.

Comment: @IslamBouderbala **try** is in the wrong place because the purpose of **try..finally** is to protect a resource against an error that might occur _between_ **try** and **finally**. The resource you want to protect in this case is the object created and assigned to `b`. But you can't protect something that might not even exist. If you get an error in your call to `capture` then nothing will be assigned to `b` but you'll still try to destroy `b` in the **finally** block. This is very likely to cause another error, hiding your previous error; making it much more difficult to debug.

Comment: I agree with @David and HeatWare - It's definitely worthwhile spending some time getting into the habit of formatting (indentation etc) your code tidily. Code which looks "right" has a much better chance of actually being right than code that doesn't and is much easier to assimilate when you come back to it in a few months' time.  And if you don't, you'll likely get into real problems when you have to write a routine that has more lines than the IDE edit window.